# From hex color code or RGB to color name using R

Tags: r, image-processing, colors, rgb

I'm trying to caluclate the pecentage of each color given a picture. At this step I have this output:

```
       Color Count red green blue
861  ED1B24 16774 237    27   36
1    000000 11600   0     0    0
18   23B14D  5427  35   177   77
1996 FFFFFF  5206 255   255  255
1547 FEF200  3216 254   242    0
862  ED1B26   344 237    27   38
```

Now I would like to add another column with the color name and then compute the percentage. How can I do it? I guess I also have to aggregate some colors.
Tnx

Here the discussion with the code for the above output: [Image colors composition using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104206/image-colors-composition-using-r)

Comment: Related: [Find color names for colors close to colorBrewer palette](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408333/find-color-names-for-colors-close-to-colorbrewer-palette). See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach is similar to @Richard Ambler's solution to compare distance between test rgb vector and
expansive set of colour mapping from output of `colours()`.

The function `rgb2col` below with given test rgb values returns approximate matching colour name

**Data:**

```
library(scales) #for function show_col

DF = read.table(text="Color Count red green blue
 ED1B24 16774 237    27   36
 000000 11600   0     0    0
 23B14D  5427  35   177   77
 FFFFFF  5206 255   255  255
 FEF200  3216 254   242    0
 ED1B26   344 237    27   38",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


 #from https://gist.github.com/mbannert/e9fcfa86de3b06068c83

 rgb2hex <- function(r,g,b) rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 255)
```

**Function:**

```
 rgb2col = function(r,g,b) {

 #create colour name vs. rgb mapping table 
 colourMap = data.frame(colourNames = colours(),t(col2rgb(colours())))

 #input test colours
 testDF = data.frame(colourNames="testCol",red = r,green = g,blue = b)

 #combine both tables
 combDF = rbind(testDF,colourMap)

 #convert in matrix representation 
 combMat= (as.matrix(combDF[,-1]))

 #add row labels as colour names
 rownames(combMat) = combDF[,1]

 #compute euclidean distance between test rgb vector and all the colours
 #from mapping table 
 #using dist function compute distance matrix,retain only upper matrix
 #find minimum distance point from test vector

 #find closest matching colour name
 approxMatchCol = which.min(as.matrix(dist(combMat,upper=TRUE))[1,][-1])

 #compare test colour with approximate matching colour
 scales::show_col(c(rgb2hex(r,g,b),rgb2hex(colourMap[approxMatchCol,2:4])))

 #return colour name
 return(approxMatchCol)

 }
```

**Output:**

```
sapply(1:nrow(DF),function(x) rgb2col(DF[x,"red"],DF[x,"green"],DF[x,"blue"]))
#firebrick2      black   seagreen      white     yellow firebrick2 
#       135         24        574          1        652        135
```

**Plots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could decide on some distance metric and then search for the R colour that minimizes the distance to each of your colours. It sounds computationally expensive but it actually turns out to be pretty instantaneous.

For example, using the data frame that you have presented:

```
> col_data
      Color Count red green blue
861  ED1B24 16774 237    27   36
1    000000 11600   0     0    0
18   23B14D  5427  35   177   77
1996 FFFFFF  5206 255   255  255
1547 FEF200  3216 254   242    0
862  ED1B26   344 237    27   38
```

We could create another data frame containing the RGB values for the colours defined in R:

```
r_colors <- data.frame(color = colors())
r_colors <- cbind(r_colors, t(col2rgb(colors())))
```

This creates something that looks like:

```
> head(r_colors)
          color red green blue
1         white 255   255  255
2     aliceblue 240   248  255
3  antiquewhite 250   235  215
4 antiquewhite1 255   239  219
5 antiquewhite2 238   223  204
6 antiquewhite3 205   192  176
```

(dot dot dot)

```
> tail(r_colors)
          color red green blue
652      yellow 255   255    0
653     yellow1 255   255    0
654     yellow2 238   238    0
655     yellow3 205   205    0
656     yellow4 139   139    0
657 yellowgreen 154   205   50
```

Using Euclidean distance to map the colours in `r_data` above:

```
col_data$color_name <- sapply(
  seq_along(col_data$Color),
  function(i) 
    r_colors$color[
      which.min(
        (r_colors$red - col_data$red[i])^2 +
          (r_colors$green - col_data$green[i])^2 +
          (r_colors$blue - col_data$blue[i])^2
      )
    ]
)
```

We get the data frame:

```
> col_data
      Color Count red green blue color_name
861  ED1B24 16774 237    27   36 firebrick2
1    000000 11600   0     0    0      black
18   23B14D  5427  35   177   77   seagreen
1996 FFFFFF  5206 255   255  255      white
1547 FEF200  3216 254   242    0     yellow
862  ED1B26   344 237    27   38 firebrick2
```

Of course, the colours might not match exactly, but they are pretty similar. The following image shows the colours in `col_data` (on the left) next to the corresponding nearest R colour (right).

[image: Comparison of colours to nearest neighbour in RGB-space]

(Technically, we are simply searching for the nearest neighbour in RGB-space.)

If I understand the second part of your question correctly, to get the relative proportions from this point shouldn't be too tricky.